# Select a class which is part name and part variable

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3

I want to select elements with the class **.group .level3**

Here is what I have now

```
var level = 3;
Y.all(".group" '.level'+[levelnumber])
```

That is what I have now but don't know where all the quotation marks should go.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the **square braces**

Also you have some syntax errors with the statement. ".group .level" is a string and you want to concatenate a variable to it

```
Y.all(".group" '.level'+[levelnumber])
             ^ ^      ^ ^           ^
             ------------------------   Get rid of these
```

---

```
Y.all(".group .level"+ levelnumber)
```

You generally tend to use `[]` to access a specific index in Array like objects.